# Como redireccionar al directorio raiz al acceder a un directorio

Tags: html, .htaccess, seguridad

Buenas, tengo un problema, estoy haciendo una pagina y al momento de introducir un directorio, carga una pagina la cual muestra todos los archivos o directorios que contiene el directorio actual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo redireccionar al usuario a la pagina home e impedir que el usuario visualice el contenido del directorio o entre a directorios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a asumir que estás usando Apache como servidor web (teniendo en cuenta que usas un archivo .htaccess), esto lo agregas en tu .htaccess de la carpeta raíz pública de tu sitio web:

```
# No mostrar listados de directorios
Options -Indexes

# Redirigir al directorio raíz desde /error/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^error/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]

# También podrías usar
# RedirectMatch 301 ^/error/$ http://www.misitio.com/
```

Comment: Option -Indexes me redirecciona a la pagina 404 del hosting

Comment: Ten en cuenta que es el plural "Options", también es posible que tu hosting no permita usar esa regla.

Comment: `Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403    /error/error404.html` Logre solucionarlo con el anterior codigo, Options -Indexes arroja un error 403 y lo capture con la segunda linea redireccionandolo a la pagina error404.html